# Properties of Integration

Tags: integration

In my text book the properties of integration written are:

1 $$P_1$$ $$\int_a^b f(x)dx =\int_a^b f(t)dt$$
2 $$P_2$$ $$\int_a^b f(x)dx =-\int_b^a f(x)dx$$
3 $$P_3$$ $$\int_a^b f(x)dx =\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$
4 The proof of the last property goes on like this:

5 Proof of $$P_3$$
6 Let$$ t=a+b-x$$
7 Then $$dt=-dx$$
8 When $$x=a, t=b $$
9 and when $$x=b, t=a$$
Therefore

10 $$\int_a^b f(x)dx =-\int_b^a f(a+b-t)dt$$
11 $$=\int_a^b f(a+b-t)dt$$  by $$P_2$$
12  $$=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx $$
by $$P_1$$
13 Please tell what is wrong in my interpretation:

14 If $$t=a+b-x$$   then  $$ x=a+b-t$$ then from the first line of proof(10), can't we equate the Right Hand side to $$\int_b^a  f(x)dx $$?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For 2.), did you mean $$-\int_{b}^a f(x)dx?$$

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/HtWFL2nQH4xnin4X9

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to make it clear:

- $P_1$: you can change the dummy variable;
- $P_2$: if you swap the bounds, the sign of the integral changes;
- $P_3$: by the change of variable $t=a+b-x$, $dx$ becomes $-dt$, but the new bounds must be swapped ($a+b-a=b, a+b-b=a$), and you can compensate the two effects.

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=-\int_{a+b-a}^{a+b-b} f(a+b-t)\,dt=-\int_b^a f(a+b-t)\,dt=\int_a^b f(a+b-t)\,dt.$$

Comment: Currently, your statement $P_3$ is wrong.

Comment: If I swap the a+b-t by x and -dt by dx then the integral becomes $$\int_b^a f(x)dx$$

Comment: @ShreyaSoni: nope. Do it step by step.

Comment: What about line 12

Comment: I know my interpretation is exactly negative of what it should be, but in that last property, the substitutions makes me ending up on that last integration.

Comment: @ShreyaSoni: 11. and 12. are fine.

Comment: Because they are part of proof.

Comment: @ShreyaSoni: what you want is less and less clear to me.

Comment: If in line 11, I substitute a+b-t by x(as in line 6 it is already mentioned a+b-x=t so a+b-t=x) in the function and -dt by dx (by taking the negative outside the integral inside to make it -dt, see line 7) then can't I arrive on the integral of line 14?

Comment: @ShreyaSoni: sorry, your explanations are full of shortcuts, I cannot follow. 14. is the original integral, so what ?

Comment: 14 ain't the original integral as the limits are flipped

Comment: @ShreyaSoni: oops, yes. My previous remark still holds.

Comment: Let me do it on a paper and attach the link to it

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/HtWFL2nQH4xnin4X9